# Delphi XE 32-bit signed representation

Tags: delphi, bit-manipulation, 32-bit, delphi-xe

Does anyone know if the 32-bit signed representation has been changed in Delphi XE?

I have the following code, that works fine in Delphi 5:

```
table: array[0..255] of LongInt =
($00000000, $77073096, $EE0E612C, $990951BA,
$076DC419, $706AF48F, $E963A535, $9E6495A3,
$0EDB8832, $79DCB8A4, $E0D5E91E, $97D2D988,
$09B64C2B, $7EB17CBD, $E7B82D07, $90BF1D91,
$1DB71064, $6AB020F2, $F3B97148, $84BE41DE,
$1ADAD47D, $6DDDE4EB, $F4D4B551, $83D385C7,
$136C9856, $646BA8C0, $FD62F97A, $8A65C9EC,
$14015C4F, $63066CD9, $FA0F3D63, $8D080DF5,
$3B6E20C8, $4C69105E, $D56041E4, $A2677172,
$3C03E4D1, $4B04D447, $D20D85FD, $A50AB56B,
$35B5A8FA, $42B2986C, $DBBBC9D6, $ACBCF940,
$32D86CE3, $45DF5C75, $DCD60DCF, $ABD13D59,
$26D930AC, $51DE003A, $C8D75180, $BFD06116,
$21B4F4B5, $56B3C423, $CFBA9599, $B8BDA50F,
$2802B89E, $5F058808, $C60CD9B2, $B10BE924,
$2F6F7C87, $58684C11, $C1611DAB, $B6662D3D,

$76DC4190, $01DB7106, $98D220BC, $EFD5102A,
$71B18589, $06B6B51F, $9FBFE4A5, $E8B8D433,
$7807C9A2, $0F00F934, $9609A88E, $E10E9818,
$7F6A0DBB, $086D3D2D, $91646C97, $E6635C01,
$6B6B51F4, $1C6C6162, $856530D8, $F262004E,
$6C0695ED, $1B01A57B, $8208F4C1, $F50FC457,
$65B0D9C6, $12B7E950, $8BBEB8EA, $FCB9887C,
$62DD1DDF, $15DA2D49, $8CD37CF3, $FBD44C65,
$4DB26158, $3AB551CE, $A3BC0074, $D4BB30E2,
$4ADFA541, $3DD895D7, $A4D1C46D, $D3D6F4FB,
$4369E96A, $346ED9FC, $AD678846, $DA60B8D0,
$44042D73, $33031DE5, $AA0A4C5F, $DD0D7CC9,
$5005713C, $270241AA, $BE0B1010, $C90C2086,
$5768B525, $206F85B3, $B966D409, $CE61E49F,
$5EDEF90E, $29D9C998, $B0D09822, $C7D7A8B4,
$59B33D17, $2EB40D81, $B7BD5C3B, $C0BA6CAD,
$EDB88320, $9ABFB3B6, $03B6E20C, $74B1D29A,
$EAD54739, $9DD277AF, $04DB2615, $73DC1683,
$E3630B12, $94643B84, $0D6D6A3E, $7A6A5AA8,
$E40ECF0B, $9309FF9D, $0A00AE27, $7D079EB1,
$F00F9344, $8708A3D2, $1E01F268, $6906C2FE,
$F762575D, $806567CB, $196C3671, $6E6B06E7,
$FED41B76, $89D32BE0, $10DA7A5A, $67DD4ACC,
$F9B9DF6F, $8EBEEFF9, $17B7BE43, $60B08ED5,
$D6D6A3E8, $A1D1937E, $38D8C2C4, $4FDFF252,
$D1BB67F1, $A6BC5767, $3FB506DD, $48B2364B,
$D80D2BDA, $AF0A1B4C, $36034AF6, $41047A60,
$DF60EFC3, $A867DF55, $316E8EEF, $4669BE79,
$CB61B38C, $BC66831A, $256FD2A0, $5268E236,
$CC0C7795, $BB0B4703, $220216B9, $5505262F,
$C5BA3BBE, $B2BD0B28, $2BB45A92, $5CB36A04,
$C2D7FFA7, $B5D0CF31, $2CD99E8B, $5BDEAE1D,
$9B64C2B0, $EC63F226, $756AA39C, $026D930A,
$9C0906A9, $EB0E363F, $72076785, $05005713,
$95BF4A82, $E2B87A14, $7BB12BAE, $0CB61B38,
$92D28E9B, $E5D5BE0D, $7CDCEFB7, $0BDBDF21,
$86D3D2D4, $F1D4E242, $68DDB3F8, $1FDA836E,
$81BE16CD, $F6B9265B, $6FB077E1, $18B74777,
$88085AE6, $FF0F6A70, $66063BCA, $11010B5C,
$8F659EFF, $F862AE69, $616BFFD3, $166CCF45,
$A00AE278, $D70DD2EE, $4E048354, $3903B3C2,
$A7672661, $D06016F7, $4969474D, $3E6E77DB,
$AED16A4A, $D9D65ADC, $40DF0B66, $37D83BF0,
$A9BCAE53, $DEBB9EC5, $47B2CF7F, $30B5FFE9,
$BDBDF21C, $CABAC28A, $53B39330, $24B4A3A6,
$BAD03605, $CDD70693, $54DE5729, $23D967BF,
$B3667A2E, $C4614AB8, $5D681B02, $2A6F2B94,
$B40BBE37, $C30C8EA1, $5A05DF1B, $2D02EF8D);
```

However, when I try to compile it using Delphi XE, I get the following error message:

```
[DCC Error] CRC32.pas(34): E2026 Constant expression expected
```

In some elements like:
$EE0E612C
$990951BA
$E963A535
(and others, but not all of them).

Does anyone know why does it happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: oh, dear. why in the jupiter sake you want polynomial to be Lognint? it a kludge ascending to TP7 lacking proper unsigned type! (more than 15 years old)

Comment: This system I'm migrating from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE is more than 15 years old =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Delphi 2006 constants are treated as unsigned numbers. You should replace $EE0E612C
 with longint($EE0E612C) etc.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
table: array[0..255] of LongWord =
```

The constants with the most significant bits set to 1 are not accepted as longint values because it is signed.

LongWord is unsigned. And had no such problems.

You still can use LongInt but you have to convert the constants to the 0..7FFFFFFF range and add a minus if they are negative.

And yes, Delphi XE (and 2010) is a lot more picky on those details which isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Using LongWord (or Cardinal) is the solution. But the error message is wrong. FWIW: In D2007, I get two messages: The correct one (about violated bounds) and the one Marcela quotes.